# Map function usage and declaration to quick navigation

Tags: javascript, php, phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc

PhpStorm has feature to quickly navigate to the function declaration.

In my current work project I faced with situation where usage function name is generated depends of used component.

> component 1

```
function selectOneFile(id){
    //complex logic
}
```

> component 2

```
function selectTwoFile(id){
    //another complex logic
}
```

> Place where function gets called

```
<?php $components = [0  => 'One', 1 => 'Two'] ?>

var fileId = $(someComponent).data('id');
select<?php echo $components[$_POST['component_id']]  ?>File(fileId);
```

I can't rewrite function to be

```
selectFile(fileId,'<?php echo $components[$_POST['component_id']]  ?>');
```

because inside the logic of this functions is very different.

Also I can't use just one name for this function because is one case this components is loaded on one page, and on another case it loaded only one component on page.

I want to navigate between function declaration and it usage: when I press `Ctrl+B` on `selectOneFile(id)` it would show me usage

```
select<?php echo $components[$_POST['component_id']]  ?>File(fileId)
```

and when I press `Ctrl+B` on

```
select<?php echo $components[$_POST['component_id']]  ?>File(fileId)
```

I would to see declarations `selectOneFile(id)` and `selectTwoFile(id)`.

Is there any way to make mapping between declaration and usage?

Comment: AFAIK -- no (at very least I'm unaware of such tags or other functionality). **P.S.** I've added `webstorm` tag hoping for JB devs to notice this question -- they may have different opinion on this (if it's possible and how .. or what other options might be available).

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for your comment. How you think is that feature is needed or it's just bad code in the project?

Comment: As for me -- it's a code that can be written better. In my opinion (general case) code must be written once in advance (so it can be fully tested; easier to read and debug etc) and programmer should use certain design patterns/configs to execute stuff differently (e.g. Strategy pattern; simple if-else based on some parameter etc) instead of writing such dynamically generated code.

Comment: @LazyOne I'm totallu agree with you. Unfortunally most of current project code written in bad style. It was written before me. New code I write in good style, but when I need to fix some old components or write new feature for it I have no way instead of using as same logic. And just looking at this situation I required to use something like this feature because PM doesn't let time to refactor this component to more convenient code. Will wait WebStorm JB devs opinion.